# Who are these 'Incredibles' superheroes?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero, disney, pixar, the-incredibles

[image]

The one in the foreground is obviously Mr. Incredible, but who are the ones in the background?

Comment: Well the one on the bottom is definitely frozone...

Comment: the winged one is falcon girl I think.  the one above her wasnt that the one who.........got into a hurrican thanks to the cape (or if female the one who got into the airplane engine?

Comment: @Thomas - There ain't no Falcon Girl in the Incredibles.

Comment: There's no help in "The Art of The Incredibles". I did learn that the poster above is a variant of [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PtoTp.png), both drawn by Paul Rogers

Answer (score 32):

A few of the ['supers'](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Supers) in the pictures are identifiable; [**Frozone**](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Lucius_Best) by his distinctive ice trail, [**Dynaguy**](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Dynaguy) by his helmet crest and [**Meta-Man**](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Meta-Man) by his trademark pose.

The others depicted don't appear in the film or any of its associated materials, in particular;

- There are only [two](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Plasmabolt) known [supers](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Lightbug) with wings (both *insectile*, one fictional)
- No known supers have a spaceman-type helmet
- The third super along could be [**Apogee**](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Apogee) or [**Stormicide**](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Stormicide) (neither have a cape and both are capable of self-powered flight) but we really can't say. My gut feeling is that it's Stormicide since she appears to be [emitting gases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d73WtJlko9E&feature=youtu.be&t=20m44s)

[image]

Comment: I was thinking the "No capes" scene might reveal more info; but they are  the same supers that are depicted in the "eliminated" scene... I questioned the thoroughness of your research... I apologize haha

Comment: Dynaguy has a cape in the photo, but the figure on the poster doesn't.  That could be [Gamma Jack](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Gamma_Jack), with his wavy hairstyle (although it looks like Gamma Jack might also have a cape).